# Is it a good idea to template based on enums?

Tags: c++, enums, uniqueidentifier

I am writing a unique ID generator which has different strategies for generating Id's which are unique through a day, or a week or a month.
I do not want to create a hierarchy of classes with virtual function mechanism

Is doing something like the below code snippet, a good idea?
Any suggestions?

```
enum Duration { Day, Week, Month };

template <Duration d>
class IDGenerator
{
   generateId();
}
```

Comment: That will work perfectly fine, the respective `if` clauses will be optimized out entirely in this case. Do note that it is not 100% as powerful as specializing the class template on a type (though many/most people will prefer "less power" here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it acceptable and will work just file ***if compile-time polymorphism is enough for you*** - you will save on virtual calls and that will allow for better compiler coptimizations.

Answer (score -1):

As it stands above, it is needlessly confusing. Just create three classes with different names.

Comment: And add a class each time he extends the enum with, say, `Hour`, `Year` and so on?

Comment: @Space: If that is confusing, he just create typedefs as `typedef IDGenerator<Day> DayIDGenerator` etc. No need to create three classes with different names!

Comment: @aioobe: The template would only help if he had a sensible default implementation. It really depends on how `generateId()` is implemented. He might be able to just make the `Duration` a parameter of that function.

Comment: How is it confusing? It's confusing if you don't understand templates, in which case you shouldn't be reading C++ code that uses them. Using inheritance instead as a blunt instrument because you can't be bothered to learn how a basic function template works is silly.

Comment: @aioobe, @Nawaz: Ok, I concede. I guess this has its merits.

Comment: @Tomalak: Doesn't it depend on how `generateId()` is actually implemented? If he has to create a specialization for each of the cases, what has he gained?

Comment: @Space: What has he lost? You seem to be saying "this is bad" with no rationale other than "how is it good?", which isn't really saying anything at all.

Comment: @Tomalak: It would be bad because he would not have chosen the simplest tool to accomplish the job.

Comment: @Space: We don't know what the job is. And you have asserted that templates are more complicated than an inheritance tree of different types, which is not necessarily true at all.